# Find the number of ways to choose `n` objects from `r` objects with repetition so that every object has a matching neighbour

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

For example, if `n` is 5 and `r` is 2, it would mean the number of lists below:

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
[1,1,1,2,2]
[1,1,2,2,2]
[2,2,1,1,1]
[2,2,2,1,1]
[2,2,2,2,2]
```

which is **6**.

If `n` is 4 and `r` is 3:

```
[1,1,1,1]
[1,1,2,2]
[1,1,3,3]
[2,2,1,1]
...
[3,3,3,3]
```

which is **9**.

where each item has a neighbour whose value is the same.

For example, `[1,2,1,1,2]` is not counted, because both `2` are alone.

## Goal

Your task is to write a program/function which takes two inputs in any order, and which produces the required output.

## Detail

You can assume that `r≥2`.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Bonus

Multiply your score by **0.3** if the complexity of your program is below O(e^n).

For example, 10 bytes becomes 3 bytes.

## Testcases

Can be generated from [this Pyth test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JELqV%2Bdb%2Bbdlf%26F|VPyTtyT%7BmtjdJr%5EJQ%5EJh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A5%0A4%0A4%0A6%0A3%0A8%0A2&debug=0&input_size=2).

Usage: two lines per testcase, `n` on top, `r` below.

```
n r output
2 5 5
4 4 16
6 3 33
8 2 26
```

## Additional information

When `r=2`: [OEIS A006355](http://oeis.org/A006355).

Comment: what about ranking complexities from O(n^k) to O(n), craming all approaches below O(r^n) in one jar isnt that judicious (in addition that i dont claim this knowingly of any solution-shortcut)

Comment: @Jakube Yes you can.

Comment: I don't understand those test cases. In particular, if `n=2`, then there can only be `r` solutions i.e. two of the same object.

Comment: @Neil Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Jakube Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Also, you're using the `O` notation wrong - being `O(e^n)` means being not asymptotically greater than `e^n` - so `n` is `O(e^n)`, and being "less than `O(e^n)`" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @proudhaskeller Colloquially, "less than O(something)" means "has an upper bound of less than something". As the meaning is understood, extra qualifications are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 14 bytes * 0.3 = 4.2 bytes

```
*Quh*~+ZGtQtE0
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*Quh*~%2BZGtQtE0&input=2%0A5&test_suite_input=2%0A5%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A20&debug=0&input_size=2). Input `r` on the first line and `n` on the second line.

Complexity is `O(n)`.

#### Explanation:

Let `f(n, r)` be the number of ways to create such a list with the last number being `0`. Obviously it doesn't matter if we take `0` or any other number.

It's easy to see, that the following recursion holds:

```
f(n, r) = 0                                  ... if n < 2
f(n, r) = sum(f(i, r), i <= n-2) * (r-1) + 1 ... otherwise
```

If `n == 0`, than the list cannot end with the number `0`. If `n == 1`, than the only number in the list has no neighbor. Therefore both cases have the value zero.

If `n >= 2`, than it could end in 2, 3, ... n zeros. The digit before the last zero can be any of the number 1, 2, ..., r-1. These are `r-1` possibilities. Therefore I'll add up all `f(i,n)` and multiply by `r-1`. At the end I'll have to add 1 (for the case that all digits are zeros).

The result to the question than is: `r * f(n, r)`, since the list can end in any of the `r` numbers.

In my code I make use of the predefined variable `Z = 0`. It will contain the last computed sum so far.

```
*Quh*~+ZGtQtE0   implicit: Q = first input number (r)
  u        tE0   start with G=0, do the following input-1 (n-1) times:
     ~+ZG           add G to Z
   h*~ Z tQ         and update G to the value Z*(Q-1) + 1 
                    (using the old value of Z)
*Q               multiply the result with Q
```

Comment: Explanation please? :)

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: @jakube  how much a detailed explanation costs ? (joking but i m very excited for the algorithm behind this)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 64 (70 * 0.3 = 21) bytes

```
(n,r)=>[...Array(n)].map((m,i,a)=>a[i+2]=(s=s+m|0)*~-r+r).slice(-2)[0]
```

Now runs in linear time!

Comment: How does it not qualify for the bonus?

Comment: @KennyLau The number of calls required is the nth Fibonacci number.

Comment: I see. Not memoized...

Comment: Well, you could just translate the Pyth algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 16.5 (55 bytes)

```
r#n=l!!(n-1)where l=0:r:r:w l;w(x:y:s)=r*(x+y)-x:w(y:s)
```

It uses this recursive definition:

```
f(n,r) = r*f(n-2,r) + (r-1)*f(n-3,r)
```

and uses `O(n)` time.
Usage: evaluate `r#n`

Comment: Isn't the above solution O(e^n)?

Comment: @KennyLau Pretty much like the javascript answer, this is less than `2^n`, and `phi^n` calls, and `phi<2<e`

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities), every thing of the form `O(k^n)` where `k>1` counts as `O(e^n)`...

Comment: Its not about the exact value of base, but the form of the time complexity. So for practical purposes, this is exponential.

Comment: @KennyLau that may be the notation some people use for "exponential", I do not know, but if you would actually look up the definition of big O notation, you would see that if `0<x<y` then `O(x^n)` is asymptotically smaller than `O(y^n)`, so `O(2^n)` applies for the bonus. If you would like the bonus to apply when the program uses less than exponential time, please write so in the challenge.

Comment: @Optimizer oh, I see. the `e` is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṗŒɠ€’Ạ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzulHJ51c8KhpzaOGmQ93gRjB/w8vV/r/30hHwfi/qY6CCQA)

### How it works

```
ṗŒɠ€’Ạ€S - Main link. Takes r on the left and n on the right
ṗ        - n'th Cartesian power of [1,2,3,...,n]
   €     - Over each:
 Œɠ      -   Lengths of adjacent elements
    ’    - Decrement, mapping 1 to 0 and everything else to a positive integer
      €  - Over each:
     Ạ   -   All non-zero?
       S - Sum, counting the 1s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
#oΛtgπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xzn/3OyS9PMN////N/lvDAA)

### Explanation

```
#oΛtgπ
     π cartesian power n of range 1..r
#o     number of lists which satisfy
    g   adjacent elements grouped
  Λ     all the groups
   t    are non empty when popped from
```