# Smallest groups in an array

Tags: code-golf, number, array

#### Introduction

Let's observe the following array:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

A **group** consists of the same digits next to each other. In the above array, there are 5 different groups:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]

 1, 1, 1 
          2, 2
                1, 1, 1, 1
                            2, 2, 2
                                     1, 1, 1
```

The smallest group of these is `[2, 2]`, so we output `[2, 2]`.

Let's take another example:

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4]

 3, 3, 3
          4, 4, 4, 4
                      5, 5
                            4, 4
                                  3, 3
                                        4, 4
```

You can see that there are multiple groups with the same length. The smallest groups are:

```
[3, 3], [4, 4], [4, 4] and [5, 5].
```

So we just output `[3, 3], [4, 4], [4, 4], [5, 5]` in any reasonable format. You may output these in any order.

#### The Task

Given an array consisting of only positive integers, output the smallest group(s) from the array. You can assume that the array will contain at least 1 integer.

#### Test cases

```
Input: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
Output: [4]

Input: [1]
Output: [1]

Input: [1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100]
Output: [1, 1], [100, 100]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79007/find-the-number-of-ways-to-choose-n-objects-from-r-objects-with-repetition-s).

Comment: can the input be a string?

Comment: @downrep_nation Hmm, how would you want to do that then? If you can do it with multidigit integers, than it's fine.

Comment: ints are very limited by size and strings are not. thats why im asking

Comment: @downrep_nation Okay, so how do you want to provide the input then for the last test case? `11101010100100` doesn't seem correct for input :p.

Comment: @Adnan i didn't even think of that, logical fallacy.

Comment: In an x86 asm answer, I'm thinking of a function that takes input and output pointers to arrays of 32bit integers.  I'm not sure how to delimit groups in the output.  Would a -1 element or something be acceptable?

Comment: Would a string of space-separated integers be acceptable?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd say that a pointer to an array of array pointers is the proper way to represent the output.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you give an example of how you want to provide the input?

Comment: @Mego Yes, that is acceptable.

Comment: @Adnan: The input is a single flat array.  So I was thinking of a function signature like `int smallest_groups(int *dst, int *src, int len_of_src)`.  The caller allocates a `dst` as large as the `src`... oh wait, with group separator sentinel elements added in, `dst` can take more space than `src`.  Caller allocates twice as much space as `src`?  Or what if I `write(2)` each group to stdout with a separate system call for each group?  A reader on the other end of a pipe would in theory have `read` return separate buffers for each group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <del>14</del> <del>12</del> 11

```
mM_MmhbrQ8
```

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mM_M.mhbrQ8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+4%2C+4%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+10%2C+10%2C+10%2C+100%2C+100%5D&debug=0)

2 bytes thanks to Jakube! And 1 byte thanks to isaacg!

Unfortunately, run length decoding doesn't quite do what we want it to do, but it will work with a minor workaround, but that makes it slightly longer than the manual implementation:

```
mr]d9.mhbrQ8
```

Credit to Jakube for finding this out.

Comment: Btw, rld works, but you have to provide a list of pairs: `mr]d9.mhbrQ8`

Comment: More about run length decoding: Run length decoding expects a list of pairs, such as what run length encoding returns, not an individual pair.

Comment: `.bmYN` == `mM_M`

Comment: @isaacg Ah, right that makes sense, I guess I wasn't thinking through that enough. Also that map trick is neat, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
MinimalBy[Length]@*Split
```

This is a composition of two functions that can be applied to a list. `Split` takes all groups of consecutive numbers, and `MinimalBy[Length]` selects those with minimal length.

Comment: Damn, just fired up Mathematica to test this... +1 :)

Comment: Now I'm wondering if I haven't made this too trivial :/.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
argmins length.group
```

Usage example: `argmins length.group $ [3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,3,3,4,4]` -> `[[4,4],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5]]`.

Build groups of equal elements and find those with minimal length.

Comment: Where’s the documentation for `Data.Lists`?

Comment: @Lynn: [Data.Lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists-0.4.2/docs/Data-Lists.html). See also the links to the re-exported modules on this page. `argmins` for example is from [Data.List.Extras.Agrmax](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-extras-0.4.1.1/docs/Data-List-Extras-Argmax.html).

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 120 bytes

```py
import re
r=[x.group().split()for x in re.finditer(r'(\d+ )\1*',input())]
print[x for x in r if len(x)==min(map(len,r))]
```

Takes input as a string of space-separated integers with a trailing space, and outputs a list of lists of strings. The strategy is to find groups using the regex `(\d+ )\1*` (which matches one or more space-separated integers, with a trailing space), then split them on spaces into lists of integers, and print those groups whose length is equal to the minimum group length.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/vIQf9G)

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 204 bytes

```
void f(string o){var r=Regex.Matches(o,@"([0-9])\1{0,}").Cast<Match>().OrderBy(x=>x.Groups[0].Value.Length);foreach(var s in r){foreach(var z in r)if(s.Length>z.Length)return;Console.WriteLine(s.Value);}}
```

I don't know if using a string is fair considering all the golfing esolangs get their input in the same way but he requested array input.

[image: thats how it looks]

ungolfed:

```
    public static void f(string inp)
    {

        var r = Regex.Matches(inp, @"([0-9])\1{0,}").Cast<Match>().OrderBy(x => x.Groups[0].Value.Length);

        foreach (Match s in r)
        {
            foreach (Match z in r)
                if (s.Length > z.Length)
                    return;

        Console.WriteLine(s.Value);
        }


    }
```

I need a way to get the smallest matches for the match array, most of my bytes are wasted there, help appreciated. I'm trying to get into LINQ and lambda stuff.

Comment: Technically a string is an array.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.x, 303 bytes

```
x=input()
r=[q[2]for q in filter(lambda l:(len(l[2])>0)&((l[0]<1)or(x[l[0]-1]!=x[l[0]]))&((l[1]>len(x)-1)or(x[l[1]]!=x[l[1]-1]))&(len(filter(lambda k:k==l[2][0],l[2]))==len(l[2])),[(a,b,x[a:b])for a in range(0,len(x))for b in range(0,len(x)+1)])]
print filter(lambda k:len(k)==min([len(s)for s in r]),r)
```

Ugliest. Code. Ever.

Input: An array in the format `r'\[(\d,)*(\d,?)?\]'`
In other words, a python array of numbers

Output: An array of arrays (the smallest groups), in the order that they appear in the input array

Additional Coincidental Features (Features that I did not intend to make):

- The input can be an empty array; the output will be an empty array.
- By changing `min` to `max`, it will return an array of the largest groups.
- If you just do `print r`, it will print all of the groups in order.

Answer (score 2):

## Retina, <s>91</s> <s>85</s> <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

```
M!`\b(\d+)(,\1\b)*
(,()|.)+
$#2:$&
O#`.+
s`^(.*\b(.+:).*)¶(?!\2).+
$1
.+:
<empty-line>
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=TSFgXGIoXGQrKSgsXDFcYikqCigsKCl8LikrCiQjMjokJgpPI2AuKwpzYF4oLipcYiguKzopLiopwrYoPyFcMikuKwokMQouKzoK&input=MSwxLDEwLDEwLDEwLDEwMCwxMDA)

### Explanation

The input is `1,1,10,10,10,100,100`.

The first line matches groups with same terms:

```
M!`\b(\d+)(,\1\b)*
```

The input becomes:

```
1,1
10,10,10
100,100
```

The following two lines prepend the number of commas to the line:

```
(,()|.)+
$#2:$&
```

The input becomes:

```
1:1,1
2:10,10,10
1:100,100
```

Then they are sorted by this line, which looks for the first number as index:

```
O#`.+
```

The input becomes:

```
1:1,1
1:100,100
2:10,10,10
```

Then these two lines find the place where the length is different, and remove everything onwards:

```
s`^(.*\b(.+:).*)¶(?!\2).+
$1
```

The input becomes:

```
1:1,1
1:100,100
```

Then the numbers are removed by these two lines:

```
.+:
<empty-line>
```

Where the input becomes:

```
1,1
100,100
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>70</s> 65 bytes

*Edit: -5 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(x)(y=split(x,diffinv(!!diff(x))))[min(l<-lengths(y))==l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxNDoIwEAXgPafgZzOT1AWoO3sSMIZUik2GgdBi4PQV6UKCk2/xMi95o7ddTdRY92jHfhqs9Hpi5UzPMCMs0g5kHMziabQ2/IYk@aa1W6/sDAPdTtRw614WFkQp6X6cBAW5iINik@8UhydipGoHaZZlFVecYvQ/dxZxcNm5bkL@tYj@Aw)

This feels rather clunky, so I won't be surprised if there's a much slicker [R](https://www.r-project.org/) way to do this...  *Edit: [there is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216382/95126)...*

```r
function(x)             # x is vector of values;
(y=                     # define y as
  split(x,              # groups of values of x that share the same
          cumsum(       # cumulative sum of
          x!=c(0,x))))  # 1 if different to the next element;
[                       # now, get element(s) of y
 (l=lengths(y))         # whose length(s)
        ==min(l[l>0])]  # equal the smallest non-zero lengths of y
```

Comment: Would `rle` be handy here?

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Po0Kzusi2KCcVyODKsc3NzNMoUskBMhMLCnIqgeyyaCDf1jYnVqcotUAnR7P2/38A) is 58

Comment: @Giuseppe - Nice!  And 56 bytes by including the variable defs into the function def.  Post it.  I thought about ```rle```, but didn't try it because it seemed to me that it would be too verbose to 'rebuild' the groups.  Obviously I was wrong...

Comment: Done! And as a bonus [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcxNDoIwEAXgPafgZzOT1AWoO3sSMIZUik2GgdBi4PQV6UKCk2/xMi95o7ddTdRY92jHfhqs9Hpi5UzPMCMs0g5kHMziabQ2/IYk@aa1W6/sDAPdTtRw614WFkQp6X6cBAW5iINik@8UhydipGoHaZZlFVecYvQ/dxZxcNm5bkL@tYj@Aw) tweaking your approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, <s>22</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
I0;œṗ¹L=¥ÐfL€Ṃ$$
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=STA7xZPhuZfCuUw9wqXDkGZM4oKs4bmCJCQ&input=&args=WzEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDEsIDFd&debug=on)

```
I0;œṗ¹L=¥ÐfL€Ṃ$$     Main link. List: z = [a,b,c,...]

I                    Compute [b-a, c-b, d-c, ...]
 0;                  Concatenate 0 in front: [0, b-a, c-b, d-c, ...]
   œṗ                Split z where the corresponding item in the above array is not zero.
      L=¥Ðf          Filter sublists whose length equal:
           L€Ṃ$      the minimum length throughout the list.

     ¹         $     (grammar stuffs)
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 15 bytes

```
Y'tX<tb=bw)wTX"
```

[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WSd0WDx0Yj1idyl3VFgi&input=WzEsIDEsIDEwLCAxMCwgMTAsIDEwMCwgMTAwXQ)

Input is a vector, like `[1 2 3 4]`, and output is a matrix where each column is one of the smallest groups, e.g.:

```
1 100
1 100
```

for the third test case.

Explanation:

```
Y'    %// Run length encoding, gives 2 vectors of group-lengths and values
t     %// Duplicate group lengths
X<    %// Minimum group length
tb    %// Duplicate and get vector of group lengths to the top
=     %// Find which group lengths are equal to the minimum
bw)   %// And get the values of those groups
wTX"  %// Repeats the matrix of minimum-length-group values by the minimum group length
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 106

```js
a=>(a.map((v,i)=>v==a[i-1]?g.push(v):h.push(g=[v]),h=[]),h.filter(x=>!x[Math.min(...h.map(x=>x.length))]))
```

**Test**

```js
f=a=>(a.map((v,i)=>v==a[i-1]?g.push(v):h.push(g=[v]),h=[]),h.filter(x=>!x[Math.min(...h.map(x=>x.length))]))

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
, [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4]
, [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
, [1]
, [1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100]]
.forEach(t=>console.log(t+' -> '+f(t).join` `))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Does `h.map(length)` not work?

Comment: @KennyLau no, for it to work `length` should be a function with the string as argument, not a method of string

Comment: @edc65 Actually, a property of String. Not a method.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 113 bytes

```
a=>a.map(n=>n==c[0]?c.push(n):b.push(c=[n]),c=b=[])&&b.sort((a,b)=>a[l]-b[l],l='length').filter(e=>e[l]==b[0][l])
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 25 chars

```
{z/⍨(⊢=⌊/)≢¨z←(1,2≠/⍵)⊂⍵}
```

In English:

- put in z the argument split where a number is different than the one preceding;
- compute the length of each subarray
- compare the minimum with each of the lengths producing a boolean...
- ... that is used to reduce z

Comment: Commute. Commute. Commute! `⍵⊂⍨1,2≠/⍵`

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), 31 bytes

```
[:(#~[:(=<./)#@>)]<;.1~1,2~:/\]
```

Input is an array of values. Output is an array of boxed arrays.

### Usage

```
   f =: [:(#~[:(=<./)#@>)]<;.1~1,2~:/\]
   f 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
┌─┐
│4│
└─┘
   f 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 4 4 3 3 4 4
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│5 5│4 4│3 3│4 4│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

### Explanation

```
[:(#~[:(=<./)#@>)]<;.1~1,2~:/\]  Input: s
                              ]  Identity function, get s
                         2       The constant 2
                             \   Operate on each overlapping sublist of size 2
                          ~:/      Check if each pair is unequal, 1 if true else 0
                       1,        Prepend a 1 to that list
                 ]               Identity function, get s
                  <;.1~          Using the list above, chop s at each true index
[:(             )                Operate on the sublists
             #@>                 Get the length of each sublist
     [:(    )                    Operate on the length of each sublist
         <./                     Get the minimum length
        =                        Mark each index as 1 if equal to the min length else 0
   #~                            Copy only the sublists with min length and return
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 65 bytes

```
#(let[G(group-by count(partition-by + %))](G(apply min(keys G))))
```

Uses `+` as `identity` function as `(+ 5)` is 5 :) The rest should be obvious, `G` is a hash-map used as a function and given a key it returns the corresponding value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḅlᵒlᵍh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GO1pyHWycBcW/G///RCtGGOgoQZARGhkjICE0wVifaWEcBgkyQkCkYQdgIWaBqZGOgEiBRuIyhATKGELEKsQA)

Input through the input variable and output through the output variable.

```
ḅ         The list of runs of consecutive equal elements of
          the input
 lᵒ       sorted by length
   lᵍ     and grouped by length
          has the output variable
     h    as its first element.
```

Although, unlike `ḅ`, `ᵍ` groups non-consecutive equal elements, the `lᵒ` is still necessary to find the group with the shortest lengths, and it works because the order of groups in the output from `ᵍ` is determined by the position of the first element of each group, so that `ᵍhᵐ` could function as sort of a *deduplicate by* pseudo-metapredicate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=pairkeys,min -a`, 69 bytes

```perl
map$r{y/ //}.="[ $_]",pairkeys"@F "=~/((\d+ )\2*)/g;say$r{min keys%r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUClqLpSX0Ffv1bPVilaQSU@VkmnIDGzKDu1sljJwU1BybZOX0MjJkVbQTPGSEtTP926OLESqCc3M08BpEa1qPb/f0MFCDQCQyjrX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAyDtk1lcYmUVWpKZYwuzQwdo0H/dRAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
←kLg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbhGyf9P///0cb6gChARyBcSwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒgLÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opHSfwxMe7mz6f7j9//9oQx0FCDICI0MkZIQmGAsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
γé¬gù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3ObDKw@tST@88///aGMdBQgyQUKmYARhI2RjAQ)

**Commented**:

```python
γ      # split into chunks of equal adjacent elements
 é     # sort the chunks by length
  ¬    # get the shortest (first) chunk without popping the list
   g   # take the length of that chunk
    ù  # keep all chunks with this length
```

[Try it with step-by-step output!](https://tio.run/##XY7BasMwEETv/YohpxR6a0IgUPohpQfF2Vgby5KSXRP6SYXeeuq1ueeXHNmya1MxoIWZtztBzI6pbZHfguvouGAF@9joFov15vj68nD7HnxJdmdqQGEbXwnCAXRqjIPZH01BXkGO6vTLH43r50CHs0ItjezuA458qXaK4verj5aUk2ITQ6JYHvgs@phRXFhtaBQxxMi@7KOORWeLUHZ71FSU3f5QV1et0bxmnsb1J8Urogjj3Niwu5MAln9F2/bt@QlZq5nWvfI8ue93)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a 2D-array.

```
òÎüÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=8s78yg&input=WzEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDEsIDFdCi1R)

```
òÎüÊ     :Implicit input of array
ò        :Partition between elements where
 Î       :  The sign of their difference is truthy (not 0)
  ü      :Group and sort by
   Ê     :  Length
         :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

```r
function(x,r=rle(x),l=min(r$l))lapply(r$v[r$l==l],rep,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqfItignVaNCUyfHNjczT6NIJUdTMyexoCCnEsguiwbybW1zYnWKUgt0cjT/p2kkaxjqKECQERgZIiEjNEFNTa7kxBINJWVl5Zi8mDwlTS6QAcY6ChBkgoRMwQjCRshqav4HAA)

-2 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen. Uses `rle` and `rep` to collapse and reconstruct the array.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 24 bytes

```
{{x=&/x:#'x}#(&~=':x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs6qurrBV06+wUlavqFXWUKuzVbeq0IyvqOXiSlPXMFQwVDACQmMgNLHWMbQGCRgawBEYQwTB6gwVEGwoz9oYohsKTYEQREPFNAEu5BlD)

- `(&~=':x)_x` split the input on indices where the values change
- `{x=&/x:#'x}#` filter down to items of the minimum length

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 36 bytes

```
[ [ ] group-by values all-shortest ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwDEX3nsIXaESBCRY2xMKCmKoOITIlIkqK7SAqlLOHQAE9/8FPX/pnbSRQPh52@@0KNHMwDD2FOFjfK3wIaYYrkkcHjLeI3iD//EAoMg5kvcC6qp7QFOaFRWEJ6WPS1zez/01JuYUWummtPo1w1y4ig3au5ksgQRbospDdlJ5SqnTfT34B)

- `[ ] group-by values` Split a sequence into groups of contiguous equal elements.
- `all-shortest` Take all the shortest groups.

`[ stable-slices all-shortest ]` would work except it doesn't have the right behavior for 1-element inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ĉş
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuOdB6dv6Q4KbkYKrDgZla0oQ4IGgGhoQ6CDeXFckUb64CgCRSaAiGIhooB5WE6wCIgPlTM0ACOwDgWYiUA)

```
ĉ       Split the input into chunks of equal elements
 ş      Find the shortest chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 97 bytes

```javascript
x=>eval(`[[${x}]]`.replace(/\b(\d+),(?!\1\b)/g,'$1],[')).filter((t,_,x)=>!x.some(y=>t[y.length]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7PCoJAEAbwe0@hEDhL24ZWR@1BVtFVp83YXHE3UaJntz8eEg/B7zDMB9/MVXTCFG3V2G2tSxzNTSiFxqay1ffGhGMfRtgJBRnn60f/TJKMtdgoUSDs4hzickMonNzYj3Oyk9Rb@wnlHiHsXCmLLYClKe1JGLk9M/qGMISR5QNTWEt7SQgZC10brZApLWFxHrhPnUnw5c8Ei@W7a/W3a0@dyWHm@DXNv/Tz1ws)

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://tio.run/##fc7BCoJAEAbge09hEDRL24pWt1YfZJNcdNqM1RV3EyV6dis9FB6C7zDMD//MTbbSZk1Ru21lchxsKbVG686qMffa8qHjEbZSQyrE6tE9kyRlDdZaZgg@xEcOp3xDCIV4eQqIr@g6oWJNCLsU2mED4OiZdoRHy45ZUyL0PHKiZxor5a4JIUNmKms0Mm0UzK6DCKg3CUfBj3C2fHct/nbtqDfZ/ziMpvmbfv56AQ) works

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) for Windows, 88 bytes

```powershell
$h=@{}
$args|%{$i+=$p-ne$_;$h.+$i+=,$p=$_}
($g=@($h|% v*|sort c*))|? c*t -eq $g[0].count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFBboMwELz7FSu0FDsxUShwaYXKH3qMIlRRF1IhoMZpIwFvpwuEhhxrrb3eGXvWGtfVj9JNropiwA@IoB0wj@K2Z/ims6azWzxtI6zdUmHyjPluO9YS6wiTnnHMophj3tnwvemaShtIN0J0L5QMuOoLMDvsj7u0Opdm6BljMWdMcoi5JyR4IK4F7SU8TuFPERAd3NPefj3nhU6NtDdnAkdsueb/ia0inGLe39jpvi/9KQcyuMuhDIVgTEAHNrQMaJA5WgKqS61So97JN0xmQqvmXBgCHsjOmI6xNf5qNFH8Wk2OjRYn7md1Kh0JTk@ldcDkaPViBsGZBcZeF@q1SCy9/yNiIb89hL5nLSqeVo@0WD/8Ag)

The script uses the Powershell alias `sort` that should be `sort-object` with Linux.

Less golfed:

```powershell
$hashTable=@{}
$args|foreach-object{
    $i += ($prev -ne $_)
    $prev = $_
    $hashTable.+$i += ,$prev
}
$groups=@($hashTable|foreach-object Values|sort-object Count)
$groups|where-object count -eq $groups[0].count
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 46 bytes

```arturo
$=>[c:chunk&=>[&]select c=>[=size&size min c]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?gNzxBg)